# Automatic migrations or code based migrations ? Which is better choice?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.3, entity-framework-migrations

I am trying to decide code first migration strategies but not sure that which is better one.

I actualy liked automatic migrations but not sure that it can create more headache.

I have read [this article](http://elegantcode.com/2012/04/12/entity-framework-migrations-tips/) and he is advocating code-based migrations. But i will not need to switch to different state in migrations so i will always use latest one and i am working in the project as single developer.

Suggestions ?

Answer (score 2):

Automatic migrations were initially also referred as "with-magic migrations" whereas code-based migrations were referred as "no-magic migrations". These two names reflect exactly what is going on. Automatic migrations are implicit - you simply don't care and let them run as they need to. Code-based migrations are explicit - you define migrations in predefined steps and EF guides you in this (for example by not allowing more than one pending migration).

If you just want to have your database always up to date and you don't expect to support multiple versions or downgrades you should be OK with automatic migrations.